# Access to the complete \ShipoutBox (LaTeX hooks)

Tags: shipout, lthooks

The following small sample document shows the manipulation of the \ShipoutBox (mirroring as an example) using a LaTeX hook. The background is not mirrored as it is not yet part of the box. This is an expected problem (see the "ltshipout-doc" documentation). How do I manage to minipulate the complete box including foreground and background? Is there a LaTeX hook missing?

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext,xcolor,pict2e,graphicx}
\usepackage[left=30mm,right=30mm]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
%\pagestyle{empty}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
  \put(0,0){\color{red!30}\circle*{2\paperwidth}}%
}

\AddToHook{shipout/before}{%
  \setbox\ShipoutBox=\vbox{\moveright1in\box\ShipoutBox}%
  \setbox\ShipoutBox=\hbox to\paperwidth{\box\ShipoutBox\hss}%  
  \setbox\ShipoutBox=\hbox{\reflectbox{\box\ShipoutBox}}%
  \setbox\ShipoutBox=\vbox{\moveleft1in\box\ShipoutBox}%
}

\begin{document}
  \rule{\textwidth}{1mm} \par
  \blindtext \par \vfill \blindtext
  \newpage
  \rule{\textwidth}{1mm} \par
  \blindtext \par \vfill \blindtext
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
The example below shows how to mirror the pages including the background. Although it works that way, I would like a solution based directly on the LaTeX hooks.

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext,xcolor,pict2e,graphicx}
\usepackage[left=30mm,right=30mm]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\usepackage{atbegshi}

\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
    \put(0,0){\color{red!30}\circle*{2\paperwidth}}%
  }%
}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \setbox\AtBeginShipoutBox=\vbox{\moveright1in\box\AtBeginShipoutBox}%
  \setbox\AtBeginShipoutBox=\hbox to\paperwidth{\box\AtBeginShipoutBox\hss}%  
  \setbox\AtBeginShipoutBox=\hbox{\reflectbox{\box\AtBeginShipoutBox}}%
  \setbox\AtBeginShipoutBox=\vbox{\moveleft1in\box\AtBeginShipoutBox}%
}

\begin{document}
  \rule{\textwidth}{1mm} \par
  \blindtext \par \vfill \blindtext
  \newpage
  \rule{\textwidth}{1mm} \par
  \blindtext \par \vfill \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The June 2023 LaTeX release offers the new hook "shipout". It allows a generic solution to the problem (see `texdoc ltshipout`):

```latex
\listfiles
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext,xcolor,pict2e,graphicx}
\usepackage[left=30mm,right=30mm]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
   \put(0,0){\color{red!30}\circle*{2\paperwidth}}%
}

\AddToHook{shipout}{%
   \setbox\ShipoutBox=\vbox{\moveright1in\box\ShipoutBox}%
   \setbox\ShipoutBox=\hbox to\paperwidth{\box\ShipoutBox\hss}%
   \setbox\ShipoutBox=\hbox{\reflectbox{\box\ShipoutBox}}%
   \setbox\ShipoutBox=\vbox{\moveleft1in\box\ShipoutBox}%
}

\begin{document} \Large
   \blindtext\par \vfill \blindtext
   \newpage
   \blindtext\par \vfill \blindtext
\end{document}
```